# java stream api: поиск элемента в коллекции

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть коллекция. Необходимо найти элемент по заданному id.
Затем взять этот элемент, изменить один параметр и сохранить в БД.

В случае отсутствия такого элемента, надо создать новый объект и его сохранить в БД.
Я справился только с первым пунктом, но дальше не понимаю как быть

```
orderItemList.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getProduct().getId().equals(orderItemDto.getProduct().getId()))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(p -> orderItemRepository.save(p));
```

Если элемента нет, то:

```
orderItemRepository.save(new OrderItem());
```

Answer (score 2):

мне кажется, что все можно проще:

```
orderItemRepository.save(orderItemList.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getProduct().getId().equals(orderItemDto.getProduct().getId()))
        .findFirst().orElse(new OrderItem()));
```

если нужны дополнительные манипуляции с объектом в случае, если он был найден в стриме, то можно сделать так:

```
orderItemRepository.save(orderItemList.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getProduct().getId().equals(orderItemDto.getProduct().getId()))
        .findFirst()
        .map(p -> {
            p.setProductCount(p.getProductCount() + orderItemDto.getProductCount());
            return p;
        }).orElseGet(OrderItem::new));
```

Comment: я забыл указать, что в случае нахождения такого элемента, с ним надо еще пару манипуляций сделать перед сохранением.
простите, я не очень понял как комментарии форматировать..

`p.setProductCount(p.getProductCount() + orderItemDto.getProductCount());`
`orderItemRepository.save(p);`

Comment: @Maksim Petrov ответ дополнил

Answer (score 0):

Так попробуйте

```
Optional<OrderItem> orderItem = orderItemList.stream()
.filter(p -> p.getProduct().getId().equals(orderItemDto.getProduct().getId()))
.findFirst();
if (orderItem.isPresent()) {
   orderItemRepository.save(orderItem.get());
} else {
  orderItemRepository.save(new OrderItem());
}
```